# My phone starting acting weird please help

Tags: facebook-messenger

I have been having trouble with my phone lately. I looked into my apps and there is so many that I don't understand also I have two Facebook apps running at the same time and also to Messenger apps running at the same time I then clicked into them and it said 1 is 4 pictures and once for video. When I click on the messenger it's not my normal Messenger on my phone when I'm on Messenger account looks like it's taking a picture of me my Facebook from email says a normal Facebook and then there's Facebook too and then that URL or whatever says M Facebook at the top. Also my phone contact says Milo R with a weird e-mail address that I don't understand. I really need help with this I've gone to counseling over this and phones and I thought things were going well until this happened I don't understand why this is happening to me and it's got to stop. Any help would be much appreciated please please please and thank you

Comment: You probably have been hit by some malwares. You'll need to remove them. Please give more details about your device.

Comment: Sounds like paranoia, how you possiblly know that phone takes pictures and ss? Which device you have and also few screenshots would be nice, from app manager and running processes

Comment: Please post some screenshots.